# Is the factory design pattern applicable in this situation

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

- taskA, taskB, taskC inherit from my class Task
- ContextA, ContextA2, ContextB, ContextC inherit from my class Context

Contexts have a corresponding Task as class property :

```
public abstract class Context
{
    public String CommonProperty { get; set; }

    public abstract void MethodToOverride();
}

public class ContextA : Context
{
    public TaskA Task { get; set; }

    public override void MethodToOverride()
    {
        //do stuff with this.Task and this.CommonProperty
    }
}

public class ContextA2 : Context
{
    public TaskA Task { get; set; }

    public override void MethodToOverride()
    {
        //do stuff with this.Task and this.CommonProperty
    }
}

public class ContextB : Context
{
    public TaskB Task { get; set; }

    public override void MethodToOverride()
    {
        //do stuff with this.Task and this.CommonProperty
    }
}
```

And so on...

When iterating over a list of tasks, I want to create the corresponding Context :

```
foreach (Task t in tasks)
{
    Context context;

    if (t is TaskA)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            context = new ContextA() { Task = t as TaskA};
        }
        else
        {
            context = new ContextA2() { Task = t as TaskA };
        }
    }
    else if (t is TaskB)
    {
        context = new ContextB() { Task = t as TaskB };
    }
    else if (t is TaskC)
    {
        context = new ContextC(){ Task = t as TaskC };
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Unkown Task");
    }

    context.CommonProperty = "value";
    context.MethodToOverride();//Do different things based on the context type
}
```

I feel there should be a cleaner way to achieve this but I can't figure out how to manage the creation of the context object, especially the case of contextA and contextA2 that depend on a condition.

Comment: post the context class definition

Comment: Task could have abstract or virtual method called ContructContext . In here each Task subtype can construct is appropriate context

Comment: Without seeing more, you might be more inclined to use a `Dictionary` that stores the context and simply execute based on the key that identifies the task.

Comment: Why are you using an abstract, an interface would be better suited.  Plus you won't override, as each class would hold the implementation.

Comment: @Greg I was mixed between both actually. Didn't see any particular advantage to pick itnerface over abstract class in this situation.

Comment: the condition that you check that you use to decided contextA or A2, what is that condition, where does it come from?

Comment: @Dave it's a check made ealier in the function that serves several purpose (not only to determine the type of context). You can think of it as `condition = otherObject.Date < DateTime.Now`

Comment: What about visitor pattern? You can use it to act as a factory like so: `Context getContext( TaskA task ){return new ContextA();} Context getContext( TaskB task ){ return new ContextB(); }` (details missing for brevity) ... the only thing is that condition for ContextA and ContextA2 ...

Comment: An interface does not consume your inheritance for one, simply a contract, and properly coupled with Dependency Injection would allow you to stub and mock your code as the requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Task t in tasks)
{
    Context  context = t.ConstructContext(condition);



    context.CommonProperty = "value";
    context.MethodToOverride();//Do different things based on the context type
}

public asbtract class Task
{
    //whatever might be in here
    public abstract Context ConstructContext();
}

public class TaskA : Task
{
    //NOTE: In my opinion condition should be internal to TaskA and no one else should know about and you should remove the parameter from the method
    // but I don't know where you get it from so I'm leaving it here
    public override Context ConstructContext(bool condition)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return new ContextA() { Task = this};
        }
        else
        {
            return new ContextA2() { Task = thid };
        }
    }
}

public class TaskB : Task
{
    public override Context ConstructContext(bool condition)
    {
        //ignore condition which implies it shouldn't really be passed

        return new ContextB() {Task = this};
    }
}

//etc...
```

I really don't like passing that condition about, its a code smell in my opinion, but from what you have said, it needs to be something external to the tasks. Anyway this should meet your needs

Comment: That's what I was hesitating to do. Yes the condition is annoying but it's a domain rule that specifies : if the condition is met then do things differently with the same base information. I haven't found a proper workarround.

Comment: Obviously I can't fully grasp your scenario as I dont have all the code. But if it is a domain condition, is it something that could be fetched from within Task A or passed to is constructor in some manner?

Comment: The foreach is in a repository method. The condition is fetched in the database via SQL query. I could instanciate a reposity within TaskA and get the condition like this. However that doesn't seem better and I'd still need to get the condition in the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Factory Pattern is suitable.

```
class ContextFactory {
    public create(TaskA t, bool condition) {
        return condition ? new ContextA() { Task = t } : new ContextA2() { Task = t };
    }
    public create(TaskB t) {
        return new ContextB() { Task = t };
    }
    public create(TaskC t) {
        return new ContextC() { Task = t };
    }
}
...
ContextFactory factory = //... new or passed from somewhere
foreach (Task t in tasks) {
    Context context;
    if (t is TaskA) {
        context = factory.create(t as TaskA, condition);
    } else if (t is TaskB) {
        context = factory.create(t as TaskB);
    } else if (t is TaskC)
        context = factory.create(t as TaskC);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unkown Task");
    }
    context.CommonProperty = "value";
    context.MethodToOverride();//Do different things based on the context type
}
```